# Detecting click anywhere on form (including controls) in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, events

A WinForms application, in which a certain UI control has to disappear 5 seconds after the user interacts with the window (clicking anywhere on the form including any control, or key presses).

Assuming an event is fired when this happens, the following is the event handler:

```
private async void userInteract(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBarFinished)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        statusIdle(); // this method hides a progress bar after 5 seconds. It is working.
    }
}
```

In the form constructor, the event is subscribed to as follows:

```
// at the moment, it is not working for when a user clicks anywhere on the form
// it is working when a specific control click event occurs, like this one
progressBar.Click += userInteract;
```

Subscribing to the `MouseClick` and `KeyPress` events of the `Form` itself have been tried, but the event does not seem to fire then. It's only when specific control events are used, that it works, as stated above.

Comment: Thats coz, in winforms Events dont bubble/tunnel like they do in wpf. Sounds like you want to make something like bootstrap toaster notification which fades after clicking on it.

Comment: You can trap [`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate)

Comment: you could loop through the controls recursively and add your event handler

Comment: `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` is passed by child controls to the parent Window when they're first activated by a mouse click.  You get this event from all controls, except the Form itself of course. The Form receives `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. You just need to override WndProc and activate a Timer when you trap one of those messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form’s WndProc method processes messages sent to the form by the Windows operating system. This is an extremely important method that allows forms to move, resize, repaint, and perform other critical operations.

```
    // Constants for decoding the Win32 message.
    protected const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
    protected const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    protected const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Check the Message parameter to see if the message is WM_MOUSEACTIVATE indicating that a control was clicked.
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
        {
            int wparam = m.WParam.ToInt32();

            if (wparam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || wparam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                // TODO: Do something with the mouse event.
                Console.WriteLine(m);

                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

[Ref 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ccc4e3b-0764-4f4e-8333-fd4c52ccbd28/handle-a-mouse-click-anywhere-on-the-form?forum=winforms)

[Ref 2](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/11/override-wndproc-to-see-when-the-user-clicks-any-control-on-a-form-in-c/)

Comment: `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` is sent (multiple times) if you also hover the Mouse over a Control and you don't select anything.

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks, that's true. I've updated it to check  if the message is WM_MOUSEACTIVATE indicating that a control was clicked.